# Grails 3.2.8: Java verifier error, can't get hot-reloading to work

Tags: grails, grails3

I'm trying to run a multi-project grails build on version 3.2.8. I'm getting the following on the console output:

grails.dev.Support                       : Reloading is disabled. Development time reloading requires disabling the Java verifier. Please pass the argument '-Xverify:none' to the JVM

I've tried passing the argument, but the error won't go away (and hot reloading won't work)

[image: IntelliJ build configuration]\

Thoughts/help?

(Grails 3.2.8, OSX 10.12.6, Java 1.8, IntelliJ 2017.2.4)

Comment: The following link takes you to the source of the class where the message is coming from, there are lots of ifs in there, maybe you can determine  why you're receiving the message from the source? https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/dev/Support.groovy

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was inadvertently caused by me checking in a config at some point with:

```
grails {
    agent {
        enabled = false
    }
}
```

When I was trying to use a different tool for hot reloading. Not that the message given by grails was helpful.

Now, I'm just left with the fact that things still don't reload, but I have no clue why.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue in Intellij 2018.2.6 with Grails app.

Apparently hot swap is working only in DEVELOPMENT environment. You can check it right after starting your webapp: `Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development`
 and only when you choose a Run/Debug configuration as `Grails`.

If you use `Spring Boot`/`Spring` Run/Debug configuration unfortunatelly it's not working as expected.